# Redirecionamento 301 para domínio dinâmico

Tags: c#, iis, redirecionamento-de-url, iis-7, redirect

Boa tarde pessoal.
Temos um  site **meusite.com** e nós atualizamos ele e ai domínios como **meusite.com?id=123** perderam o "rumo". 
Como faço para fazer o 301 nessas URLs dinâmicas no IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia fazer assim:

```
<script runat=”server”>
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
Response.Status = “301 Moved Permanently”;
Response.AddHeader(“Location”,”http://www.meusite.com.br”);
}
</script>
```